# Boost with CUDA

Tags: boost, cuda

I have been using Boost inside a Visual C++ CUDA project. I'm using `regex.hpp` inside a `.cu` file and it works fine including it this way:

```
#include < boost / regex.hpp >
```

Now, I need to use `abs.hpp`, which I'm including this way:

```
#include < boost / ratio / detail / mpl / abs.hpp >
```

and it fails while compiling. I'm using Windows 8 64-bits, Visual Studio 2012, Boost 1.53.0 and CUDA 5.5.

I get this error only by putting this in my code: 
`#include < boost / ratio / detail / mpl / abs.hpp >`

without using more instructions related with Boost. I have several `.cpp` and `.cu` files in my project. If I put that include in a `.cpp` file, it compiles fine. If I put that include in a `.cu`, this error appear:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   11.0\VC\include\boost/ratio/detail/mpl/abs.hpp(68): error C2675: unary '-' : 'T' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type
>   acceptable to the predefined operator

Thanks for any help you can provide and sorry for my English, it's not my native language!

Comment: If possible try to post the corresponding line over here. It is also good practice to use `.cu` just for cuda kernels.

Comment: typedef integral_c<T,value> type;
This is the line. Line 68 of the "abs.hpp" boost file.
I know that is a good practice to do what you told me but I need that functionalities inside a __ global __ function like I'm able to do it with "regex.hpp".

Answer (score 1):

There are many [built-in math functions](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/index.html) that Nvidia provides. You usually cannot use functions written for the CPU in a CUDA kernel as they will probably be missing the `__device__` decorator.

Comment: The problem is that I'm forced to use "abs.hpp" because a NoSQL Database that I'm using (MongoDB), require that Boost library.

Comment: I have no issues using the "regex.hpp" Boost library inside a CUDA kernel. The problem comes with "abs.hpp", the Boost library that require the Database I'm using.

Comment: How are you going to interface to this database from the device? Afaik that isn't possible, at least not directly.

Comment: The use of "abs.hpp" shouldn't be the same situation as "regrex.hpp"? I need to make calls to the Database methods into the "__ global __" functions because every thread need to make queries and insertions into the Database.

Comment: You first need to figure out if it is possible to interact with this database from the device. I don't have proof at hand, but I believe that it is not possible to do this.

Comment: But the problem itself now it's not the Database. I'm just trying to include a Boost library in a ".cu" file. I'm shocked because some Boost libraries works fine on the device (like regex.hpp) and some not (like abs.hpp).

Comment: Then you'll have to compile things separately and link them ie compile whatever uses this "abs.hpp" header with gcc, compile the .cu files with nvcc and link them.

Comment: A ".cu" file is the one who use the header "abs.hpp". I'm forced to compile that ".cu" file with nvcc.

Comment: But you can't compile it with nvcc. But you can compile abs.hpp with gcc. So make yet another .hpp that includes abs.hpp, which you compile with gcc and link to the other executable, compiled with nvcc. If this sounds like gibberish to you then you have other questions you should be asking.

Comment: Hey Max, I did what you told me. I added the "abs.hpp" include to a file named "aux.hpp" (which is compiled with cl) and this file "aux.hpp" is included in the ".cu" file. But the problem still exist. I did it correctly? I'm using Visual Studio.

Comment: No idea. At this point your problem is unrelated to CUDA, and since I've not used this header before I can't help you further. Good luck.

Comment: When aux.hpp includes abs.hpp, and aux.hpp is included in a cu file, then the nvcc compiler driver is processing this file, including the aux.hpp and abs.hpp that are included.  A simple solution is to limit your usage of boost to .cpp files, as has already been suggested.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. I need the functionalities of that Boost library in a ".cu" file for the reasons exposed.